# Difficulty Configuring GA4 dbt Package in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I'm a non-technical marketer new to dbt, trying to leverage the GA4 dbt package for querying my Google Analytics 4 data in BigQuery. I've successfully connected my BigQuery projectto dbt. According to the README file, I should add the following to my packages.yml file:

> ```
> packages:
>   - package: Velir/ga4
>     version: [">=5.1.0", "<5.2.0"]
> ```

However, I'm unsure how to proceed with this step and other necessary configurations. Could someone guide me on how to correctly add this to my packages.yml file and ensure the configuration is correct for a beginner in dbt?  I'm on this page, but I'm unable to create another .YML file or add anything.[image]

Comment: Can you share your setting on project and account level?